# Angular Firebase authentication emits twice - first with incomplete data

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, angularfire

I have a problem with my angular authentication emitting incorrect data using angularfire auth.

The auth flow is pretty ordinary:

- switchMap the authState user to a user document from the database
- emit the user document changes through a BehaviourSubject
- a user authenticates via oAuth
- the document in the DB is updated after sign-in with data from the oAuth provider
- a DB trigger applies some additional meta-data (e.g. last modified)

What happens when a user authenticates is that Subscribers to the BehaviourSubject receive two emissions:

1. User data based on the oAuth provider data (which is incomplete since it does not include the data in the user document), then
2. User document data from the DB - which is the complete user data

So the first emission is unwanted, it is not the data from the DB.
The second emission is the correct one.

I *think* the reason for the two emissions is that:

- First, the user update after oAuth sign-in causes an update in the local cache which is then emitted by the Observable (incomplete user data)

  - (I have tested this by disabling the update and the first emission did not occur)
- Later, the DB trigger then updates the document in the DB, and when and that data syncs with the client it is emitted from the user document observable - this time it is the complete user data.

(Persistence is not enabled, in case that makes a difference)

So my questions are:

- Is my assumption for the cause correct?  (the local update then the trigger update)
- What would be the best way to prevent the first local update and wait for the complete document?
- Should I just check for the presence of properties that are only in the DB record and ignore other changes?
- Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?